# Ignoring files and folders in an svn-controlled folder?

Tags: svn

I'm using svn on a mac. I'm trying to add an eclipse project to a repo. I want to ignore all .class files, and a few subfolders. I am using an ignore.txt file which (kind of) works. My folder structure, for example:

```
project/
   extras/
      test.class
      zips/
   blah.class
   ignore.txt
```

then my ignore.txt file looks like this:

```
*.class
extras/zips
```

so "blah.class" is ignored which is perfect, however, the "zips" folder is not ignored, nor is the "test.class" file within it.

I guess I have to create an ignore.txt file for every sub folder, I can't create one master on in the root folder like I have now?

So basically I should create an ignore.txt file inside folder "extras" with content

```
*.class
zips
```

and repeat for all my subfolders?

Thanks

------- Edited  -----------------
Edited above to reflect updated usage of an ignore.txt file using:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F ignore.txt .
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `global-ignores` in your [svn configuration file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config).

Comment: Argh sorry I updated to use an ignore.txt file, but am confused if I need an ignore.txt file for every subfolder in which I want to control ignore rules, or can I just use one top-level ignore.txt? That would be ideal, but doesn't seem to be working at the moment, thanks.

Comment: I would never use the global-ignores, cause this is limited to your client instead by using the property which is part of the project. And everyone who checks out get the ignores with properties.

Comment: Cool yeah is that the ignores file I switched to using (ignores.txt)? If so, I think I almost have it working, just confused if I need an ignores.txt per folder, or if I can have one in the root of my project folder? Thanks