# SVN Ignore issues

Tags: svn

I have searched google and tried a bunch of the suggestions but I can't seem to ignore subfolders.

Amongst other entries, in my Ignores.txt file I have these folders that are not ignored (to include the contents of those folders):

```
bin
obj
```

All the other entries specified in Ignores.txt file are ignored.

The folder structure is:

```
DataService/obj/<bunch of files and folders>
DataService/bin/<bunch of files and folders>
```

Can somebody tell me what the heck I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more clear in your question: what is not ignored? Which is your directory structure? What is the content of svn:ignore (`svn propget svn:ignore .`)?

Comment: I've updated the information to be more clear. Thanks @Matteo

Comment: Does this mean that you would like to ignore both? What is the result of `svn propget svn:ignore DataService`?

Comment: related: [Ignoring files and folders in an svn-controlled folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743931/ignoring-files-and-folders-in-an-svn-controlled-folder)

Comment: They are not under SVN control.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore will not take effect if you have already checked in your bin and obj folders.  If you have, I believe you will have to add them to the ignores list and then delete the folders using Subversion's delete functionality (i.e. not simply the operating systems delete

Comment: Setting the ignore property works that way, but it looks like he is trying to use a global (non property) way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There must have been something wrong with the Ignore.txt file. After I deleted the file, recreated and set the prop again, it worked.